# C++14 expand a tuple three by three

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, metaprogramming

I have a C++14 tuple of size multiple of 3 and I would like to expand it 3 by 3 sequentially to a function.

```
tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> a(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2);

void process_triplet(int& mystate, int a, int b, int c) {
  // do something on a b c and mystate
}

template <typename Tuple>
void process_triplets(Tuple&& tuple) {
  // how do I write over here such that I can 'sequentially' processing each triplet
  // ideally I want the following:
  // process_triplet(mystate, 1, 2, 3);
  // process_triplet(mystate, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

Need help with implementing `process_triplets` in a generic way.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need a [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and [pack-expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template <class Tuple, std::size_t... N>
void process_triplets_impl(int& mystate, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<N...>) {
    int x[] = {
        0,
        ((void)process_triplet(
            mystate,
            std::get<N * 3 + 0>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)),
            std::get<N * 3 + 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)),
            std::get<N * 3 + 2>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))
        ), 0)
        ...
    };
    (void)x;
}
template <class Tuple>
void process_triplets(int& mystate, Tuple&& tuple) {
    process_triplets_impl(
        mystate
        std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value / 3>()
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the syntax x[] = {0, (void)process_triplet() ...}?

Comment: @Jes I'm initializing an auto-sized int-array. That's to take advantage of the initializers in an initializer-list being evaluated strictly in order. The first `0` is to make sure the array has at least one element. `((void)function(...), 0)` is to make sure all the other elements evaluate to a zero int. `...` is for pack-expansion, follow the link in the post. [Fold-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) would be nicer, but were introduced in C++17.

Answer (score 0):

## Method One

It's a simple, direct and recursive method involving passing tuple from upper stage to a lower one without first three tuple elements.

```cpp
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> a(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2);

void ProcessTriplet(int a, int b, int c) { printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c); }

template <typename... Args, size_t... Ints>
void ProcessTripletsHelper(const std::tuple<int, int, int, Args...>& tuple,
                           std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
  using NextTupleType = std::tuple<Args...>;
  NextTupleType next_tuple = {std::get<Ints + 3>(tuple)...};
  ProcessTriplet(std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<2>(tuple));
  ProcessTripletsHelper(
      next_tuple,
      std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<NextTupleType> - 3>{});
}

template <>
void ProcessTripletsHelper<>(const std::tuple<int, int, int>& tuple,
                             std::index_sequence<>) {
  ProcessTriplet(std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<2>(tuple));
}

template <typename Tuple>
void ProcessTriplets(Tuple&& tuple) {
  ProcessTripletsHelper(
      std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
      std::make_index_sequence<
          std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>> - 3>{});
}

int main() {
  ProcessTriplets(a);
  return 0;
}
```

## Method Two

Here I propose another method with **nicer performance** (no runtime copy and less burden for template compiler) and **easier implementation** (no need for `std::index_sequence` and less code lines). `constexpr` is crucial here since it prevents further compilation when the type deduction reaches the end.

```cpp
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> a(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2);

void ProcessTriplet(int a, int b, int c) { printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c); }

template <size_t First, typename Tuple>
void ProcessTripletsHelper(Tuple&& tuple) {
  ProcessTriplet(std::get<First>(tuple), std::get<First + 1>(tuple),
                 std::get<First + 2>(tuple));
  if constexpr (First + 3 ==
                std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>) {
  } else {
    ProcessTripletsHelper<First + 3, Tuple>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
  }
}

template <typename Tuple>
void ProcessTriplets(Tuple&& tuple) {
  ProcessTripletsHelper<0, Tuple>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}

int main() {
  ProcessTriplets(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if constexpr` is C++17.